# Jquery cannot read property of null error

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

Hi I'm learning Jquery and I can't get it to run a function - code below.

I've set up a simple select box and then tried to add an on change event to it.  Originally I tried with a .change but then I read that using the method shown is better since it doesn't rely on the element being available at the start.

I'm just getting an error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null.  I've not used jsfiddle before but I've tried to set one up here https://jsfiddle.net/2L6z3fdm/

Help!

```
            <select id="roomCapacity" >
              <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
              <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
              <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script> 
             $( "#roomCapacity" ).on("change",function(){
                        roomLayoutBox = ["Volvo","Ford"];
                        console.log(this.value);
                        $('#roomStyle').find('option:not(:first)').remove();

                    });
            </script>
```

Comment: roomStyle is ID of which element?

Comment: You havn't got an element with an id of roomStyle (same in your fiddle).

Comment: please note that you should use delegated events (.on) only when you are adding the target element (#roomCapacity) after the page has been rendered by the browser. In this case you can use change without any problem.

Comment: Try `$(this).find('option:not(:first)').remove();` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L6z3fdm/2/)

Comment: @LelioFaieta, that's not true, even `.click` uses `.on` under the hood.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null`: This cannot come from the line `$('#roomStyle').find(...)`, because even if there's no element with id `roomStyle`, the `$()` is still not null but an empty jquery element, and `.find` still works (returning an empty element). The error must be somewhere else (or jquery does not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#roomCapacity").on("change",function(){
  roomLayoutBox = ["Volvo","Ford"];
  console.log(this.value);
  $("#roomCapacity").find('option:not(:first)').remove();
});
```

roomStyle doesnt exist in the current context :)
You can also use

```
$(this).find('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this.  I forgot to change roomStyle when I pulled the code snippet :(  What I was trying to do was adjust another select box(not shown) called room Style

Answer (score 1):

Your code should read as follows

```
$("#roomCapacity").on("change",function(){
  roomLayoutBox = ["Volvo","Ford"];
  console.log(this.value);
  $("#roomCapacity").find('option:not(:first)').remove();
});
```

`roomStyle` does not exist as the `id` for any element.